# How can I renew the \textcite command and change the delimiter for two authors of the same cite key?

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I am using the author-year style luh-ipw and need to use `\slash` as delimiter for two or more authors in the bibliography. I changed it via adding following code in the preamble:

```
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\slash}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\slash}
```

unfortunately this also affects the `\textcite` command. But instead I need the preconfigured "and" delimiter back. The biblatex option

```
maxcitenames=1
```

is not the solution.

After some research and consultancy of the biblatex-manual I tried to add

```
\renewcommand*{\textcitedelim}{\finalandcomma}
```

which I thought adds an "and"-delimiter instead of the slash. Unfortunately it doesn't do anything at all. *I only want to change the `\textcite` command* but not the `\cite` or `\parencite` commands. So the question is: **How can I renew the `\textcite` command and change the delimiter for two authors of the same cite key?**

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{bibliographie.bib}
@article{Kuyucu.2010a,
Author = {Kuyucu, Tuna and {\"U}nsal, {\"O}zlem},
Journal = {Urban Studies},
Month = {06},
Number = {7},
Pages = {1479--1499},
Title = {\enquote{Urban Transformation} as State-Led Property Transfer: An Analysis of Two Cases of Urban Renewal in Istanbul},
Volume = {47},
Year = {2010}
}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[german=quotes, strict=true]{csquotes} %Because of \enquote

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear-luh-ipw
]
{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\slash}%
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\slash}%
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}

\bibliography{bibliographie}

\begin{document}

\textcite{Kuyucu.2010a}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

It looks like

> Kuyucu/Ünsal (2010) 
>   but should more look like 
>   Kuyucu und Ünsal (2010)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a suggestion using the package `xpatch` to set the default definition of `\multinamedelim` and `\finalnamedelim` only for the bib-macro `textcite`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}



\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\let\multinamedelimorig\multinamedelim
\let\finalnamedelimorig\finalnamedelim
\xpretobibmacro{textcite}{%
  \let\multinamedelim\multinamedelimorig%
  \let\finalnamedelim\finalnamedelimorig%
 }{}{}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\slash}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\slash}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\cite{companion}\qquad\cite{knuth:ct:a}

\textcite{companion}\qquad\textcite{knuth:ct:a}

\parencite{companion}\qquad\parencite{knuth:ct:a}


\textcite{companion}\qquad\textcite{knuth:ct:a}


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be working for the first use but when I use it again, the delimiter of textcite is reset to the slash

Comment: It seems that the redefinition of \multinamedelim and \finalnamedelim after the "xpatch" of \textcite affects the behaviour of \textcite.

Comment: @Kris: I updated my example to show you, that I can't reproduce your behavior.

Comment: Ah, you were right, I was wrong. It definitely works. I also used the command \citeauthor and THIS didn't work. Is there a way to implement the behaviour into that command, too?

Comment: @Kris: Yes you can do nearly the same: `\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\let\multinamedelim\multinamedelimorig%
  \let\finalnamedelim\finalnamedelimorig%\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printnames{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}`